# Return AJAX response through a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, global-variables, response

I have a problem with my AjaxRequest() function. Here it is:

```
function AjaxRequest(url, method, data) {

var response;

$.ajax({
    method: method.toUpperCase(),
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        response = JSON.stringify(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       response = JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "AJAX Fout" });
    }
});

return response;

}
```

I want to `return` the jQuery AJAX response, but it doesn't work.
I tried to solve this problem with a callback function, but then I can't pass parameters to my function, what makes it completely useless.

Could someone help me or show me an alternative?

Comment: ajax is **asynchronous**

Comment: can also return the `$.ajax` promise